# Pass File Directory between button click

Tags: c#, wpf, parameter-passing, streamreader, buttonclick

How can I pass file directory between two button click method?

1. I'm selecting csv file and put the CSV name to TextBox

   ```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
     ofd.Filter = "CSV|*.csv";
     ofd.ShowDialog();

     csvName.Text = ofd.SafeFileName;           
   }
   ```
2. Second button should start reading CSV file selected into first step

   ```
   private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       //string path = ;
       StreamReader srd = new StreamReader();
   }
   ```

Comment: Create a form level variable and store the directory path in it in button1 click and use it in button2 click.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't do (synchronous) file I/O on the GUI thread. It will make your App appear unresponsive.

Comment: Read up on MVVM. Doing "button_Click" on WPF is painful to see because it's painful to program. You are resisting WPF if you go against it's design patterns.

Comment: To add to nvoigt's comment. The MVVM-alternative would be using [Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview).

Comment: thanks, but I need to do it in very simple way

Comment: this is complicated way. When you have 2 buttons and 1 variable it may seem as less complicated, but each addition will make your program harder to read and use. Go MVVM, use asynchronous command, maybe read up on reactive extensions. This is like saying that you don't want to put fundaments under your building, because it has only one floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csvName.Text = ofd.SafeFileName; SafeFileName doesn't return the full path it just returns the filename, which is not enough for the button(Button_Click_1) the start reading .
Instead use ofd.FileName; this give the complete path. 
Assuming csvName as TextBox.

declare global variable

```
public string FullFileName{get;set;}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Filter = "CSV|*.csv";
ofd.ShowDialog();
csvName.Text = ofd.SafeFileName;
```

FullFileName=ofd.FileName;
    }

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
using(var reader = new StreamReader(FullFileName))
{
// do your action here
}
}
```

Comment: that's correct, but I want to display just file name inside the TextBox

Comment: add a global variable to hold to file full path and use it . modified the code check it

Answer (score 0):

you can read the text of csvName in the button2_click event.

string path = csvName.Text;

or you can use a variable to save the value of the textbox and use that too.